# Query does not include the expression as a part of an aggregrate function

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

My SQL is very limited and I have been having trouble with this code which I think should be simple but I simply don't get it. I am using MS Access 2010 and SQL. I the error I am getting is query does not include the expression as a part of an aggregate function.

Here is the actual code:

```
SELECT 
    tblEmployees.LName, tblEmployees.FName, tblEmployees.Trade, 
    tblEmployees.Title, tblTrainingHistory.Date, tblCourses.CourseName,
    IIf(IsNull(CourseLength),"",DateAdd("m",[CourseLength],[Date])) AS ExpiryDate
FROM 
    tblEmployees 
LEFT JOIN 
    (tblCourses 
RIGHT JOIN 
    tblTrainingHistory ON tblCourses.CourseID = tblTrainingHistory.CourseID) 
    ON tblEmployees.EmpID = tblTrainingHistory.EmpID
WHERE 
    (((tblCourses.CourseName) In ("Course1","Course2","Course3","Course4","Course5"))
    AND ((IIf(IsNull([CourseLength]),Now(),DateAdd("m",[CourseLength],[Date])))>Now())
    AND ((tblEmployees.Active)=True))
GROUP BY 
    tblEmployees.LName, tblEmployees.FName, tblEmployees.Trade,
    tblEmployees.Title, tblTrainingHistory.Date, tblCourses.CourseName, tblEmployees.EmpID
HAVING 
    (((Count(*))=4));
```

SO what Im trying to accomplish is a query that will give me all the employees who are active in the database and they have to have all 5 courses. I can bring up people who have each course but I just need a simple list of each person that ALL the courses.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also include grouping on `CourseLength` and if I understand correctly, you want `COUNT(*) = 5`:

```
SELECT 
    tblEmployees.LName, tblEmployees.FName, tblEmployees.Trade, 
    tblEmployees.Title, tblTrainingHistory.Date, tblCourses.CourseName,
    IIf(IsNull(CourseLength),"",DateAdd("m",[CourseLength],[Date])) AS ExpiryDate
FROM 
    tblEmployees 
LEFT JOIN 
    (tblCourses 
RIGHT JOIN 
    tblTrainingHistory ON tblCourses.CourseID = tblTrainingHistory.CourseID) 
    ON tblEmployees.EmpID = tblTrainingHistory.EmpID
WHERE 
    (((tblCourses.CourseName) In ("Course1","Course2","Course3","Course4","Course5"))
    AND ((IIf(IsNull([CourseLength]),Now(),DateAdd("m",[CourseLength],[Date])))>Now())
    AND ((tblEmployees.Active)=True))
GROUP BY 
    tblEmployees.LName, tblEmployees.FName, tblEmployees.Trade,
    tblEmployees.Title, tblTrainingHistory.Date, tblCourses.CourseName, tblEmployees.EmpID,
    tblCourses.CourseLength
HAVING 
    (COUNT(*) = 5);
```

Another option would be to wrap any "ungrouped" columns in an `Aggregate function` like `MAX` or `MIN`.

Comment: I had the grouping on date already and I did add the grouping on courselength and now I am not getting any errors but I am not getting any data either and I know there is data that matches the criteria. I should have 77 People on the list

Comment: How would I wrap them?

Comment: I apologize, if you refer to my updated question I've already corrected for the inclusion of `Date`.  Wrapping a column would be achieved like so: `MAX([CourseLength])`

Comment: I do not believe the simple grouping would be the result of your not receiving any results.  I would recommend revisiting your `WHERE` clause and `HAVING` to ensure your criteria matches.  One way I achieve this is by systematically removing one clause as a time until I have identified the culprit.

Comment: Where would I put the Max([CourseLength]) in the code? Sorry I am really new to all this!

Comment: Ok, So I backed off the "Having" and I got a list of people who have taken ANY of those courses. I need just a list of who HAVE taken ALL courses.

Comment: The `MAX(column name)` would replace anywhere you use the column in the `SELECT` line or the `HAVING`.  You would then be able to remove that column from the `GROUP BY`.  But I think you're doing the right thing by just revisiting your criteria, try reducing the `HAVING` clause to `COUNT(*) = 1` and see what the results are.

Comment: I got a syntax error when I tried to add the Max(CourseLength) in... took it back out and changed the count to 1.... its not giving me all the correct data either.

Comment: I apologize, I do not have the time to continue trouble shooting (I'm at work).  I would recommend starting from scratch on your criteria, and adding one back at a time until you find the clause causing the problem.  Because I've answered your original question of the error it's up to you if you'd like to accept my answer. If you require more assistance with your query you might consider creating a new question for it.  I wish you the best of luck and I'm sorry I haven't been able to help with your results.